# Setting variable with csname in loop gives only last value

Tags: tex-core, loops

I want to define some variables calculated in a loop to draw a path in tikzpicture. The variables are defined by some length (in pt) and the (section) title. For example, let's say we have:

- 5pt, Section 1
- 10pt, Section 2
- 15pt, Section 3

This is done by a small calculation & reference on the section labels (to get the title):

```
\setcounter{sectionCounter}{0}\relax\loop\ifnum\thesectionCounter<3%
\newcount\frameNumber
\frameNumber=...
\dimen1=\textwidth
\multiply\dimen1 by \frameNumber
\divide\dimen1 by \inserttotalframenumber
\edef\progressbarwidthx{\the\dimen1}
\def\titlexyz{\nameref{\secLabel}}

\expandafter\def\csname sWidth\the\value{sectionCounter} \endcsname{\progressbarwidthx}
\expandafter\def\csname sTitle\the\value{sectionCounter} \endcsname{\titlexyz}%

\stepcounter{sectionCounter}\relax\repeat%
\leavevmode%
```

But if I call the variables after the loop by

```
\csname sWidth0 \endcsname
\csname sTitle0 \endcsname; %      
\csname sWidth1 \endcsname
\csname sTitle1 \endcsname; %        
\csname sWidth2 \endcsname
\csname sTitle2 \endcsname
```

all have assigned the same value from the last iteration: 15pt & Section 3

In the fist iteration sWidth0 & sTitle0 get the right value 5pt & Section 1, but already in the second iteration sWidth0 & sWidth1 and sTitle0 & sTitle1 get have the same values 10pt and Section 2, respectively.

Where is the problem?

Edit: I a generate this by hand the error does not occur:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{sectionCounter}
\setcounter{sectionCounter}{0}

\expandafter\newcommand\csname ary\the\value{sectionCounter} \endcsname{first}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname arz\the\value{sectionCounter} \endcsname{firstx}
\stepcounter{sectionCounter}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname ary\the\value{sectionCounter} \endcsname{second}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname arz\the\value{sectionCounter} \endcsname{secondx}

\csname ary0 \endcsname
\csname ary1 \endcsname

\csname arz0 \endcsname
\csname arz1 \endcsname

\end{document}
```

gives

```
first
second

firstx
secondx
```

Comment: Their value is `\progressbarwidthx` and `\titlexyz` respectively, not the expansion of these (because of the use of `\def` instead of `\edef`. The expansion takes place when you print them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
\expandafter\edef\csname sWidth\the\value{sectionCounter} \endcsname{\progressbarwidthx}
\expandafter\edef\csname sTitle\the\value{sectionCounter} \endcsname{\titlexyz}%
```